# Как подключить отладчик GDB для Qt Creator 2.5.2 под виндовс?

Tags: отладка, gdb, qtcreator, qt, c++

При отладке Qt программы ругается на отсутствие отладчика. Облазил все меню настроек, но так и не нашел, где нужно указать путь до отладчика.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Нашел. См. скриншот:

[image]