# Настройка отладчика MinGW в QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Поставил по умолчанию Qt. Запускаю, но отладчик не подключен. Пытаюсь настроить в Инструменты, Параметры, Сборка и запуск - не получается...

Comment: А можно поподробнее? Что конкретно не получается? Вот, например, настройки в моей венде: C:\QtMingw\Qt5.4.0\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\gdb.exe

Comment: просто пишет - отладчик не задан... выбираю комплект MSVS2013 64bit - отладчик не задан, создал свой комплект с мингв с отладчиком... всё равно не работает

Comment: Ну, для MSVS это нормально, для того, чтобы заработал отладчик, SDK нужно ставить. А вот вариант с MinGW непонятен. QtCreator должен автоматом подхватывать найденные отладчики. У меня он автоматом четыре нашел. Путь, который я приводил выше, расположен в Build&Run->Debuggers->Path. А что там у Вас сейчас?

Comment: GNU gdb 7.8 for MinGW 4.9.1 32bit C:\Qt\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\gdb.exe GDB

Comment: какая у вас версия QtCreator?

Comment: Qt Creator 3.3.2 (opensource)
Based on Qt 5.4.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)

Comment: посмотрите тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/400255/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-gdb-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-qt-creator-2-5-2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81/410486#410486

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле помимо создания комплекта с заданным отладчиком - его еще надо установить в качестве текущего комплекта для проекта. Для этого надо на главном экране *Qt Creator* зайти во вкладку Проекты (*Projects*), нажать вверху кнопку "*Добавить*", выбрать там новый созданный комплект с отладчиком - после этого он появится. Далее кликнуть по нему мышкой, чтобы этот комплект стал текущим для данного проекта. После этого старый комплект можно удалить.